# Prove that the following map has at least $k-2$ fixed points

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

This was an exercise in my algebraic topology class:

Let $S^1$ denote the circle and $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is a continuous map with a fixed point $x_0$. The induced homomorphism by $f$ between the fundamental groups is multiplication by $k$: $f_\ast: \Pi_1(S^1, x_0)\to \Pi_1(S^1, x_0): [g] \mapsto k[g].$

1. Prove that $f$ has at least $k-2$ fixed points (excluding $x_0$).
2. Give an example of such a map with exactly $k-1$ fixed points.

For the first question, we got the hint to consider $f$ as a map $f':[0,1] \to S^1$ with $f'(0) = f'(1) = x_0$ and to look at its lifts to the universal cover $\mathbb{R}$. I tried using the lifting correspondence and to find the order of $p^{-1}(x_0)$ where $p$ is the covering map, but got stuck...

For the second part, I took the map $f(z) = z^k$ (since we can pick $x_0 = 1$ by applying a rotation of the circle if necessary). This map has the $k-1$th roots of unity as fixed points and the induced homomorphism corresponds to multiplication by $k$.

Can anyone give a (second) hint for the first question? Is my answer on the second question correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the universal covering of $S^1$ to be $\Bbb R$ identifying
$S^1$ with $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$. The lifting of $[0,1]$ to a map
to $\Bbb R$ satisfies $f'(0)=a$ and $f'(1)=a+k$ for some
$a$. At a fixed point
of $f$ one has $f'(x)-x\in\Bbb Z$. On $[0,1]$, $f'(x)-x$ moves
from $a$ to $a+k-1$, so surely must pass through $k-1$ integers.

Comment: $f'$ is the map in my question right? I do not see why $f'(1) = a + k$... I think my biggest problem is that I do not clearly see what the map $f'$ looks like.

Comment: @Student If you have a map $f$ from $S^1$ to $S^1$ you can lift it to a map $F$ from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. In this map $0$ and $1$ are sent to liftings of the same point in $S^1$ so $F(1)-F(0)=k\in\Bbb Z$. This $k$ determines the image of $f$ in the fundamental group of $S^1$: it is $k$ times the standard generator.

Comment: I will have to think about this, i have never encountered liftigns where both domain and image change. Thanks for the hint tough

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, Can you elaborate on your answer please? I don't understand why $f'(1) = a + k$. I know it has to do with how $f_{*}$ is defined, but don't know how to write it explicitly.