# Showing $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ has certainly $k-2$ other fixed points, besides $x_0$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I have a similar question to what was asked already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511111/prove-that-the-following-map-has-at-least-k-2-fixed-points)

But I do not really understand the answer there.

The problem is: Let $x_0 \in S^1$ and let $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be a continuous map with $f(x_0) = x_0$. Suppose moreover that the induced map $f_{*} : \pi_1 (S^1, x_0) \rightarrow \pi_1 (S^1, x_0): [g] \mapsto  k [g]$ for some $k > 2$.

(i) Show that there are certainly $k-2$ other fixed points for $f$ besides $x_0$. (hint: consider $f$ as being a map $f^{'}: I \rightarrow S^1$ with $f^{'} (0) = f^{'} (1) = x_0$ and study the lifts of $f^{'}$ to the universal covering space $\mathbb{R}$.)

(ii) Give an example of such an $f$ with precisely $k-1$ fixed points (of which $x_0$ is one).

I do not understand the hint really. How can we consider $f$ as the map $f^{'}$? And why would we do this?

I know that the fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb{Z}$, and that every covering of $S^1$ is regular. If $p: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$ is the standard covering map, then the covering transformations are the homeomorphisms $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto x + n$, for $n$ an integer. But I'm not sure how this will help me.

An elaborate answer is appreciated.

Comment: I already said in my post that it doesn't. It is not elaborate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p:t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}$ be the usual covering map of $S^1$. Since the induced map $f_*$ takes $[g]$ to $k[g]$, it is not hard to show that  the degree of the map

$$g:I\to S^1: t\mapsto e^{2\pi it}\mapsto f(e^{2\pi it})\  \text{is}\  k,$$ which means that the lift of $g,$ namely, $F:I\to \mathbb R$  satisfies

$$F(1)-F(0)=k\  \text{and of course,}\  e^{2\pi i F(t)}=f(e^{2\pi i t}).$$

Suppose that there is an $s\in I$ such that $F(s)-s=j$ for some integer $j$. Then,

$$f(e^{2\pi i s})=e^{2\pi i F(s)}=e^{2\pi i (j+s)}=e^{2\pi i s}\ \text{so}\ e^{2\pi i s}\ \text{is a fixed point of}\  f.$$

Now as $s$ goes from $0$ to $1$, $F(s)-s$ maps onto an interval containing the $k-2$ integers between the first integer greater than $F(0)$ and the greatest integer less than $F(1)$. It follows that $f$ has at least $k-2$ fixed points.

Comment: I don't understand why $F(1) - F(0) = k$? How do you see that?

Comment: Also, I have trouble understanding how $F(s) - s$ maps onto an interval containing $k-2$ integers. Can you maybe explicitly show this with one specific case?

Comment: For your first question: wlog $f(1)=1$ for convenience. It is clear that $F(1)-F(0)=F(1)$ must be an integer. Take $g$ to be $e^{2\pi it}$ a generator of $\pi_1(S^1)$. Then we are given that $f$ maps this to $e^{2\pi kit}$, whose lift is $G(t)=kt$ and satisfies $G(1)-G(0)=G(1)=k$. And since $f(e^{2\pi it})\sim e^{2\pi ikt}$, the lifts end at the same point, so $G(1)=F(1)=k.$

Comment: For your second question, $F-id$ maps $I$ to a closed interval, that starts at $F(0)$ and ends at $F(1)-1$ so there are at least $k-1$ integers in between,

Comment: How do see from this last part that $f$ has at least $k-2$ fixed points? I am confused because $p \circ (F - id) (s) = p(j)$, which implies $f'(s) - p(s) = (1,0)$. But this doesn't result in a fixed point on $f$

Answer (score 2):

The general idea here is that *loops* with a fixed class in the fundamental group are uniquely associated to *paths* between a fixed pair of lifts in the universal cover. For this answer, let's have $S^1$ be the unit circle in the complex plane and the universal cover $p:\mathbb R\rightarrow S^1$ be $p(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$ and $I=[0,1]$ so that we can talk in terms of concrete examples.

Suppose we wanted to think about the map $f(z)=z^2$ from $S^1$ to $S^1$, for instance. This, when thought of as a loop based at $1$, defines a curve which winds twice around the origin. It is, generally, reasonable to try to study a lift of this loop, but this is not possible because there is no map $\tilde f$ from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R$ so that $p\circ \tilde f = f$ - because, if we *tried* to lift $f$, we might start at $f(1)=0$ and then note that $f(e^{2\pi i t})$ has to be $2t$ plus some integer - hence $f(e^{2\pi i t})$ must equal $2t$ if we base $f(1)=0$. This obviously is not well-defined because $f(1)$ and $f(e^{2\pi i})$ are given as different values. The failure of $f$ to lift is *precisely* because $f$ is not contractible as a loop.

Thus, instead, we define $f':I\rightarrow S^1$ by $f'(t)=f(p(t))$. This changes our loop into a path - which we know that we can always lift. In particular, we can find that
$$\tilde f'(t)=2t$$
is a lift of $f'$ - so we have solved the issue. You can imagine that $f'$ is obtained by taking the domain $S^1$ of $f$ and "cutting" it at $1$, then unrolling the circle into a line segment and that this is done to avoid the issue of loops not lifting into the cover.

Once we've done that, however, we will have a much easier time; in particular, if we forget about the example $f$ we've been using and just assume it has the desired property, we can, by knowing about the fundamental group of the circle, see that $f$ has to be homotopic (assuming, without loss of generality, that $x_0=1$) to $f(z)=z^k$. Then, $f'$ must be homotopic to $kt$ relative the endpoints of the path. In particular, this means that if we lift $f'$ to a path $\tilde f':I\rightarrow\mathbb R$ with $\tilde f'(0)=0$, then $\tilde f'(1)=k$.

To finish, we just note that $f$ has a fixed point (other than $1$) exactly when $f(t)=t$ which lifts to when $\tilde f'(t) = t + m$ for some $m\in\mathbb Z$. However, the intermediate value theorem implies that such at $t$ exists for each $m\in \{1,2,\ldots,k-2\}$.

Comment: You define $f^{'} (t) = f(p(t))$. Here $p$ is the map $p: I \rightarrow S^1$? Because in a previous paragraph you let the domain be $\mathbb{R}$... Please be consistent with the notation.

Comment: @Kamil $I$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, so $p$ can be applied to elements of $I$ - unless you really insist that one define $f'(t)=f(p(\iota(t)))$ where $\iota$ is a the inclusion map $I\rightarrow \mathbb R$ (but this is uncommon to do, except perhaps when working with categories where one would write $f'=f\circ p \circ \iota$ anyways)